# How to remove leading and trailing non-alphanumeric characters of a certain string in python using regex?

Tags: python, regex, non-alphanumeric

How do I remove the leading and trailing non-alpha characters in a given string, before and after a certain substring? See the example below

`input_string = m#12$my#tr!#$g%`

`output_string = m12my#tr!g`

The substring, in this case, is `my#tr!`

How can get the output_string given the input_string?

My attempt below removes all the leading characters (including alphanumeric). See the code snippet below). I tried amending `\W+` instead of `.+` which did not work.

```
import re
input_string = "m#12$my#tr#$%"
output_string = re.sub(r'.+?(?=my#tr!)', '', "m#12$my#tr!#$g%")
```

Appreciate any thought on how I could use the regex pattern for this purpose.

Comment: Why is the `!` after tr kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to split the string around the desired substring, replace the non-alphanumeric characters in the first and last parts and then reassemble the string:

```py
import re

input_string = "m#12$my#tr!#$g%"
mid = 'my#tr!'
first, last = input_string.split(mid)
first = re.sub('[^a-z0-9]', '', first)
last = re.sub('[^a-z0-9]', '', last)

output_string = first + mid + last
print(output_string)
```

Output:

```
m12my#tr!g
```

If you use the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module from PyPi, you can take advantage of variable length lookbehinds and replace any non-alphanumeric character that is before or after the target string:

```py
import regex

input_string = "m#12$my#tr!#$g%"
mid = 'my#tr!'
output_string = regex.sub(rf'[^a-z0-9](?=.*{mid})|(?<={mid}.*)[^a-z0-9]', '', input_string)
# 'm12my#tr!g'
```

Note that if `mid` contains characters that are special to regex (e.g. `. [ { $ ^` etc) you should escape it before use i.e.

```py
mid = 'my#tr!'
mid = regex.escape(mid)
```

If you don't want to use regex at all, you could manually strip the non-alphanumeric characters out of the first and last parts. For example:

```py
import string

input_string = "m#12$my#tr!#$g%"
mid = 'my#tr!'
first, last = input_string.split(mid)
first = ''.join(c for c in first if c in string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
last = ''.join(c for c in last if c in string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
output_string = first + mid + last
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Python without using regex? Like the strip() function works?

Comment: @Mad you could manually strip the characters from the front/last parts. See my edit